# How to Remotely Log out/Revoke Access of Google Backup and Sync, and Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive, google-backup-and-sync

I am aware that one can sign out of Gmail web sessions through its main interface, and one can remove account access for devices through [Google Account > Security > Your Devices](https://myaccount.google.com/device-activity). The latter only allows you to remove access to mobile devices, not computers (see image below).

[image: Remove Account Access]

So, how can I remotely log out or revoke access of Google Backup and Sync which is installed on computers and syncing with your Google Accounts, as well as Google Chrome?

I think this is a critical security issue, especially for freelancers who worked on-site and lost their access to whatever computers they were working on. Sometimes people missed the opportunity to do it in time, due to the nature of the type of the job; or simply forgot it and only think of it couple days/weeks/months later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only achieve this by **changing your password**.

---

Apart from the browser you enable two-step verification on, enabling two-step verification will pause the sync on all Chrome browsers you're signed in to, and sign you out of all web sessions, **but it won't sign you out of Backup and Sync**.

If you go to Gmail, click on "Details" on the bottom right (under "Last account activity") then click "Sign out of all other Gmail web sessions", you will only be signed out of Google websites on browsers that aren't signed in to Chrome. So, if you're signed in to Chrome on another computer and you do that, Chrome will re-log you back in to the Google websites.

Comment: Thanks! So, basically you're saying the only way to sign out of all Google services, including web sessions, Chrome and other apps, is to change Google Account password.

What if I change my Google Account password and then change it back immediately, will that still revoke all the previous accesses?

Comment: Following up on your answer, so there is no way to revoke access of Backup and Sync on SELECTED computers, since bye changing the password it will sign out of all computers and devices, is that correct?

Comment: You can sign out of web sessions and Chrome by enabling two-step verification, but that won't sign you out of Backup and Sync. You can't change your password to one you used previously. I usually recommend a password manager, but, personally, I use my Google account password so often that it's one of the few passwords I memorize. For the rationale behind why passwords need to be changed, see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4706/176477

Comment: No, it seems like Google hasn't offered this feature whereby one can log out of specific computers. My guess is because it's a way for them to encourage people to change their password more often. Signing back in to Backup and Sync on your usual computer shouldn't take long—it's just a part of life. At one stage, I believed in an ideal world where I wouldn't have to sign back in to accounts on my usual computers, but in reality I end up doing it often. Just think of it being for the sake of good security.

Comment: "What if I change my Google Account password and then change it back immediately,..." to set and old password again as the current password you should make around 100 passwords changes first.