# How to remotely sign out from Backup and Sync?

Tags: security, google-drive, google-backup-and-sync

Suppose I have a laptop with Google Chrome and [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) installed and my Google account logged in for both of these applications. Then, if my laptop gets stolen, I want to remotely sign out my Google account from both Google Chrome and Backup and Sync. I already found out how to remotely sign out from Google Chrome: Just open your Google Account settings and under "Security" you can remove the device. But this does not log me from Backup and Sync.

**So how do I remotely sign out from Backup and Sync?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Remotely Log out/Revoke Access of Google Backup and Sync, and Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1415822/how-to-remotely-log-out-revoke-access-of-google-backup-and-sync-and-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way how to do so is to change your password which will trigger a mass logout across whole your account each time there will be a demand to access any of your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can only achieve this by **changing your password**.

---

**Some more detail:**

Apart from the browser you enable two-step verification on, **enabling two-step verification** will pause the sync on all Chrome browsers you're signed in to, and sign you out of all web sessions, **but it won't sign you out of Backup and Sync**.

Secondly, you can't remove *computers* in the security settings, only *mobile devices*.

If you go to Gmail, click on "Details" on the bottom right (under "Last account activity") then click "Sign out of all other Gmail web sessions", you will only be signed out of **Google websites** on browsers that aren't signed in to Chrome. So, if you're signed in to Chrome on another computer and you do that, Chrome will re-log you back in to the Google websites.